# In python, what does [None] do/mean during coding of class?

Tags: java, python

What does the [None] do in this code?

```
public class Example {                            //Java
     public Example (int _input, int _outputs){   //Java
          scratch = [None] * (_input + _outputs); //Python Code
```

I'm porting a python implementation into Java and need to better understand what this means. 
Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Not worthy of being an answer, but in many cases, I view `None` as being `null`.

Comment: What kind of data must be stored in `scratch` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scratch = [None] * (_input + _outputs)
```

This makes a list of length `_input + _outputs`. Each element in this list is a `None` object.
This list is assigned to a variable, named `scratch`

Answer (score 2):

`[None]` is a list containing one element, the singleton `None`, which is commonly used to represent "no value" in Python.  This list is being multiplied by the sum of the number of inputs and outputs. The resulting list will have as many references to `None` as there are inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 1):

```
[value] * number
```

means list of `number` elements, each of them is `value`.

So your code means list of `(_input + _outputs)` `None`'s

`null` is closest thing to Python's `None` I know.